# want to send an attachment after converting to docx using mail ()

Tags: javascript, php, email, ms-word

I want to make an attachment file using the docx that I have converted, the following is the convert code

```
<?php 
// membaca data dari form atas
$namaO = $_POST['nameO'];
$alamatS = $_POST['alamatS'];
$alamatO = $_POST['alamatO'];
$noT = $_POST['noT'];
$noF = $_POST['noF'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$ultahP = $_POST['ultahP'];
$standard = $_POST['standard'];
$bidang = $_POST['bidang'];
$work = $_POST['work'];
$fullT = $_POST['fullT'];
$partT = $_POST['partTime'];
// membaca data dari form bawah
$nameD = $_POST['nameD'];
$noD = $_POST['noD'];
$ttlD = $_POST['ttlD'];
$nameM = $_POST['nameM'];
$noM = $_POST['noM'];
$ttlM = $_POST['ttlM'];
$nameC = $_POST['nameC'];
$noC = $_POST['noC'];
```

this is my initiation

```
// memanggil dan membaca template dokumen yang telah kita buat
$document = file_get_contents("form.rtf");
// // isi dokumen dinyatakan dalam bentuk string form atas
$document = str_replace("#nameO", $namaO, $document);
$document = str_replace("#addressS", $alamatS, $document);
$document = str_replace("#addressO", $alamatO, $document);
$document = str_replace("#noT", $noT, $document);
$document = str_replace("#noF", $noF, $document);
$document = str_replace("#email", $email, $document);
$document = str_replace("#web", $website, $document);
$document = str_replace("#ultah", $ultahP, $document);
$document = str_replace("#standart", $standard, $document);
$document = str_replace("#bidang", $bidang, $document);
$document = str_replace("#scope", $work, $document);
$document = str_replace("#FT", $fullT, $document);
$document = str_replace("#PT", $partT, $document);
// // isi dokumen dinyatakan dalam bentuk string form bawah
$document = str_replace("#nameD", $nameD, $document);
$document = str_replace("#noD", $noD, $document);
$document = str_replace("#ttlD", $ttlD, $document);
$document = str_replace("#nameM", $nameM, $document);
$document = str_replace("#noM", $noM, $document);
$document = str_replace("#ttlM", $ttlM, $document);
$document = str_replace("#nameC", $nameC, $document);
$document = str_replace("#noC", $noC, $document);
// header untuk membuka file output RTF dengan MS. Word
header("Content-type: application/msword");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Form application terbaru.doc");
header("Content-length: ".strlen($document));
echo $document;
```

This is for conversion to documents

```
$penerima = "agung@acm-indonesia.com";
$subyek = "Application Form ".$namaO;

$messages = '<html><body>';
$messages .= '<img src="//css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
$messages .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Nama Organisasi</strong> </td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nameO']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Alamat Sertifikasi</strong> </td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['alamatS']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Alamat Operasional</strong> </td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['alamatO']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>No Telepon</strong> </td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['noT']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>No Fax</strong> </td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['noF']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Email</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Website</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['website']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Ulang Tahun Perusahaan</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['ultahP']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Standard Yang Dipilih</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['standard']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Bidang Usaha</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['bidang']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Urain Pekerjaan</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['work']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Jumlah Karyawan</strong></td><td>:</td><td>Full Time</td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['fullT']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong></strong></td><td>:</td><td>Part Time</td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['partTime']) . "</td></tr>";

$messages .= "<tr><td><strong></strong></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Nama Lengkap Direktur</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nameD']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>No. HP</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['noD']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Tempat, Tanggal Lahir</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['ttlD']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Nama Lengkap MR</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nameM']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>No. HP</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['noM']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Tempat, Tanggal Lahir</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['ttlM']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>Contact Person Lain</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nameC']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "<tr><td><strong>No. HP</strong></td><td>:</td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['noC']) . "</td></tr>";
$messages .= "</table>";
$messages .= "</body></html>";

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$kirim=mail($penerima,$subyek,$messages,$headers);
if($kirim==true){
    echo "Pesan email dengan attachment berhasil dikirim.";
}else{
    echo "Pesan email dengan attachment gagal dikirim.";
}
?>
```

I have tried various methods, but I can't help you guys advice, I can only use it to download it, but if it hasn't been used as an attachment

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the output or an error msg if there is one.

Comment: For errors that don't exist, I want to know how I can send email attachments with converted files

Comment: Save the modified document, then you can attach it and after sending the email delete the modified version.

Btw. I would recommend to use a mailer class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) which have methods for attachments included. These mailer classes follow also RFC specification to avoid rejecting of emails of the receiving e-mail server because of malformed headers or uncovered RFC requirements!